# Preventing "double" borders in CSS

Tags: css

Say I have two divs next to each other (take https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/home as reference) with a border.

Is there a way (preferably a CSS trick) to prevent my divs from appearing like having a double border? Have a look at this image to better understand what I mean:

[image: "Double" border]

You can see that where the two divs meet, it appears like they have a double border.

Comment: no, I am using this with isotope so can't use a table. divs have different sizes

Comment: Is it only an issue for you left-right, or do you also need to worry about it top-bottom?

Comment: i wish there was a nicer solution for this in CSS. :-(

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`#divNumberOne { border-right: 0; }`

Comment: This is the only real way of doing it that doesn't mess other stuff up. If you need to do multiple elements, hell, say 100 divs, you could do `div { border-right: none; } div:last-child { border-right: 1px solid black; }` which would give you the intended effect

Comment: yea, it can always be done that way, but i was wondering if there was a pure-css way of doing it, without having to use more than one class (i will have more rows and columns)

Comment: This is pure css, I used a pseudo class (last child) so I haven't modified the html in anyway, there are many pseudo classes and I would say go down this route as I don't think there is an alternative

Comment: Look into Nth Child you can do it this way using odd and even or depending on your layout you can calculate it the way you want.

Comment: Why was this accepted as the correct answer? I really don't think this is what he was looking for. This is certainly not a scalable solution either.

Answer (score 113):

If we're talking about elements that cannot be guaranteed to appear in any particular order (maybe 3 elements in one row, followed by a row with 2 elements, etc.), you want something that can be placed on every element in the collection.  This solution should cover that:

```
.collection {
    /* these styles are optional here, you might not need/want them */
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.collection .child {
    outline: 1px solid; /* use instead of border */
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-left: 1px;
}
```

Note that outline doesn't work [in older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=outline) (IE7 and earlier).

Alternately, you can stick with the borders and use negative margins:

```
.collection .child {
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
```

Comment: Very usefull. I add also `position: relative;left: 1px;`, to revert negative margin.

Answer (score 25):

HTML:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

​CSS:

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
}

div:nth-child(n+2) {
    margin-left: -1px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/D6tHK/)**

Include [ie9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) for IE8 support (it's very useful for all CSS selectors/pseudo-elements).

Comment: if you have more than one row first div in second row have no left border and with this trick divs alignment go to left for 1px

Comment: Wasn't there no more complicated version? What about elements with a larger `right-margin`?

Comment: @afshin if i don't see his layout how can i give a specific answer?

Comment: @feeela i think it's pretty basic. Anyway, `right-margin` doesn't affect `left-margin`: http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/D6tHK/1/

Comment: This solves the lateral double borders, but not the vertical ; borders in the bottom/top are still doubled. Any hints for those ?

Answer (score 23):

Another solution one might consider is using the CSS [Adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors).

#### The CSS

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div + div {
    border-left: 0;
}
```

#### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c047253f/1/)

Comment: Nice trick, thanks! I found I got better results using `border-left: none;` otherwise I have a small gap at the top left of the div!? (Firefox).

Comment: You may want to use
`div + div {
    border-left: 0;
}`

Answer (score 22):

I'm late to the show but try using the outline property, like so:

```
.item {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

Outlines in CSS do not occupy physical space and will therefore overlap to prevent a double border.

Comment: also works, when a row breaks into more rows on smaller screens - all the other answers don`t work when your divs could break into new rows. you then have at least one div with a side without a border. thx for sharing -  upvoted

Comment: Much better to have a solution than a hack. Thank you.

Comment: didn't work for me. Still got the double border and a possible bug. you could see the outline above my scrollbar, which does not happen with border.

Answer (score 7):

You can use **odd** selector to achieve this

```css
.child{
   width:50%;
   float:left;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   text-align:center;
   padding:10px;
   border:1px solid black;
   border-bottom:none;
}
.child:nth-child(odd){
   border-right:none;
}
.child:nth-last-child(2),
.child:nth-last-child(2) ~ .child{
   border-bottom:1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="child" >1</div>
    <div class="child" >2</div>
    <div class="child" >3</div>
    <div class="child" >4</div>
    <div class="child" >5</div>
    <div class="child" >6</div>
    <div class="child" >7</div>
    <div class="child" >8</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: wouldn't it be better to do nth-child(even){border-left:none;} ? That way there could be an odd number of columns...

Answer (score 5):

If the divs all have the same class name:

```
div.things {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-left: none;
}

div.things:first-child {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

There's a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roddy/h8hrC/) here.

Comment: +1 One of the few pseudo classes, that are recognized by IE 7+8…

Comment: It's not good if yours DIV are on 2 rows : you have a double border between the 2 rows..

Comment: @Didier68 That wasn't the question, though.

Comment: The question is "preventing double borders"... but without specifying whether it is laterally or vertically ... Your solution is good for <TD> for example, but not for DIVs. I give the same remark to Stephan bellow!

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. The question is about div's, the answer is about div's, the fiddle uses div's. Where are you getting td's from?

Comment: look at @cimmanon answer... It's the only good answer, which fit to the question...

Answer (score 3):

If you also need to change border colors on interaction (eg. swatch selector in a form), I found out a nice trick to do it, using a combination of negative margins, padding adjustment and transform translate. Check it out:

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 375px;
  margin-left:1px;
}

.child {
  margin-left: -1px;/* hide double borders behind their siblings */ 
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.child input {
  display:none
}

.child label {
  display:block;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  min-height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 10px; /* will be changed when input is checked */
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.child input:checked+label {
  border: 1px solid red;
  transform: translateX(-1px);
  padding-left: 11px;
  padding-right: 9px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <input id="swatch-1" type="radio" value="1" name="option" checked="true">
    <label for="swatch-1">Element 1</label>
   </div>
   <div class="child">
    <input id="swatch-2" type="radio" value="2" name="option">
    <label for="swatch-2">Element 2</label>
   </div>
   <div class="child">
    <input id="swatch-3" type="radio" value="3" name="option">
    <label for="swatch-3">Element 3</label>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following CSS to the div on the right:

```
position: relative;
left: -1px; /* your border-width times -1 */
```

Or just remove one of the borders.

Answer (score 2):

Using Flexbox it was necessary to add a second child container to properly get the outlines to overlap one another...

```
<div class="grid__container">
    <div class="grid__item">
        <div class="grid__item-outline">
              <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.grid__container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 1px 0 0; // margin-right 1px to give the correct width to the container
}

.grid__item {
    flex: 0 1 25%; // grid of 4
    margin: 0 0 1px; // margin-bottom to prevent double lines
}

.grid__item-outline {
    margin: 0 0 0 1px; // margin-left to prevent double lines
    outline: 1px solid #dedede;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just use

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

in the parent element

Answer (score 1):

My use case was for boxes in a single row where I knew what the last element would be.

```
.boxes {
  border: solid 1px black  // this could be whatever border you need
  border-right: none;
}

.furthest-right-box {
  border-right: solid 1px black !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to a 9 year old question, another clean and responsive way to achieve this is to:

- Add a `border-left` and `border-top` to the parent
- Add `border-right` and `border-bottom` to each of the children

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
```

CSS:

```
  .one{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:thin red solid;
    float:left;
  }
.two{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-style: solid solid solid none;

    border-color:red;
    border-width:1px;
    float:left;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/H7qrp/15/)
    ​

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reaction, but I just wanted to drop my 2 cents worth, since my way of doing it is not in here.

You see, I really don't like playing with margins, *especially negative margins*. Every browser seems to handle these just that tad bit different and margins are easily influenced by a **lot** of situations.

My way of making sure I have a nice table with divs, is *creating a good html structure first*, then apply the css.

Example of how I do it:

```
 <div class="tableWrap">
   <div class="tableRow tableHeaders">
     <div class="tableCell first">header1</div>
     <div class="tableCell">header2</div>
     <div class="tableCell">header3</div>
     <div class="tableCell last">header4</div>
   </div>
   <div class="tableRow">
     <div class="tableCell first">stuff</div>
     <div class="tableCell">stuff</div>
     <div class="tableCell">stuff</div>
     <div class="tableCell last">stuff</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now, for the css, I simply use the rows structure to make sure the borders are only where they need to be, causing no margins;

```
.tableWrap {
  display: table;
  }

.tableRow {
  display: table-row;
  }

.tableWrap .tableRow:first-child .tableCell {
  border-top: 1px solid #777777;
  }

.tableCell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #777777;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  }

.tableRow .tableCell:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #777777;
  }
```

Et voila, a perfect table.
Now, obviously this would cause your DIVs to have 1px differences in widths (specifically the first one), but for me, that has never created any issue of any kind. If it does in your situation, I guess you'd be more dependant on margins then.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it using this code:

```
td.highlight {
    outline: 1px solid yellow !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 3px yellow;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very old question, but it was the first google result, so for anyone that comes across this and doesn't want to have media queries to re-add the border to the right/left of the element on mobile etc.

The solution I use is:

```
.element {
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
}
```

This works because you'll see a 2px border around the element made of the border and the shadow. However, where the elements meet, the shadow overlaps which keeps it 2px wide;

Comment: FYI this only works for table elements and not on divs

Answer (score 0):

In some specific cases (e.g. if you're using grids and you are guaranteed to generate an area without "holes"), you can solve in this way:

```
.collection {
    --border: solid 1px;
    border-top: var(--border);
    border-right: var(--border);
}

.collection .child {
    border-bottom: var(--border);
    border-left: var(--border);
}
```

where `--border` is a CSS variable.

Intuitively, for each "cell" you assign only the bottom and left borders, whereas for the container you assign the top and right borders.

Demo:

```css
.collection {
    --border: solid 1px;
    border-top: var(--border);
    border-right: var(--border);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: '. .';
}

.collection .child {
    border-bottom: var(--border);
    border-left: var(--border);
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="collection">
    <div class="child">Child 1</div>
    <div class="child">Child 2</div>
    <div class="child">Child 3</div>
    <div class="child">Child 4</div>
    <div class="child">Child 5</div>
    <div class="child">Child 6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

What about giving a `margin:1px;` around your div.

```
<html>
<style>
.brd{width:100px;height:100px;background:#c0c0c0;border:1px solid red;float:left;margin:1px;}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="brd"></div>
    <div class="brd"></div>
    <div class="brd"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LJdyf/2/)**

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution to get uniform border width is to add a border to the parent element (of the same width as the border of the child elements):

[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  width: 320px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 10px solid red;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  border: 10px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
  <div class="child">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

I prefer to use another div behind them as background and delete all the borders. You need just to calculate the size of the background div and the position of the foreground divs.

Comment: I do think my solution is the best although the critics. It's the same principe as drawing a 1px table :