# prevent double border on grid

Tags: html, css

I'm implementing crossword puzzle using `css grid`

blank cells have no color. and other cells have black border.

the problem is that borders are collabsing over each other.

I've already opened [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692089/preventing-double-borders-in-css) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882924/preventing-double-borders-in-css-grid). but the proble here is that not all cells have this double border.

here is the code

```css
.crossword-board-container {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}

.crossword-board {
  background: transparent;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(5, 4em) / repeat(5, 4em);
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.crossword-board__item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="crossword-board-container">

  <div class="crossword-board">
    <!-- ROW 1 -->
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" />
    <span></span>
    <span></span>

    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" /> <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" />
    <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" />


    <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" />
    <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" />
    <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" />
    <span></span>
    <span></span>

    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" />
    <span></span>
    <span></span>

    <span></span>
    <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" />
    <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" />

    <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" />
    <span></span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this a fix design or it may vary in coming days?

Comment: its fixed, but it's more bigger that this demo. so i'd like to have dynamic solution, not adding custom border for each cell

Comment: the solutions in the question you linked apply here, examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47883004/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/54327607/8620333

Comment: check the fist answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686698/collapsing-borders-using-css-grid using box-shadow and grid-gap, I think it's the best solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move by 1px all input top & left, this will make borders collapse on each other.

Then add a padding of 1px to the container.

This will be the result.

```css
.crossword-board-container {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}

.crossword-board {
  background: transparent;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(5, 4em) / repeat(5, 4em);
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.crossword-board input {
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="crossword-board-container">

  <div class="crossword-board">
    <!-- ROW 1 -->
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" />
    <span></span>
    <span></span>

    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" /> <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" />
    <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" />


    <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" />
    <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" />
    <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" />
    <span></span>
    <span></span>

    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" />
    <span></span>
    <span></span>

    <span></span>
    <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" />
    <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" />

    <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[bB]{1}$" />
    <span></span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like you don't need padding of 1px here. It still works.

Comment: it will overflow the container,  if this is acceptable, you can omit it. :]