# Unable to style a table correctly using CSS

Tags: html, css, markdown

I use Gatsby & Markdown for my blog.

**MARKDOWN FOR THE TABLE**

```
| Syntax    | Description |
| --------- | ----------- |
| Header    | Title       |
| Paragraph | Text        |
```

I have used the following CSS for styling the table rendered by the markdown above.

```
table {
  width: 80%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

th, td {
  border: .1rem solid #999;
  padding: .2em;

}

th {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
```

However, I am not getting the desired result. There are thick borders in the table as highlighted in orange in the picture below:

[image]

I want the thickness to be `.1rem` all around.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Checkout this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692089/preventing-double-borders-in-css

Comment: Two things: A) Posting the markdown is quite pointless.We need to see the generated HTML. B) Using relative units like rem and em for thin lines is a bad idea. Computers can't display fractions of pixels, and rounding to full pixels will always result in unexact rendering. Use 1px for borders that you don't want to be thicker.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work [image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table {
  width: 80%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

table, th, td {
  border: .1rem solid #999;
  padding: .2em;

}

th {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
</style>
<body>

<table style="width:80%">
  <tr>
    <th>Syntax</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Header</td>
    <td>Title</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paragraph</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, no difference